# `dispatchGesture` ignore overlay view

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice

I'm using the `dispatchGesture` API from Android accessibility.

I've added an overlay to the screen and I'm looking for a way to dispatchGesture behind the overlay (the overlay is what's intercepting the original gesture) since otherwise the gesture is dispatched on my `OverlayView` and don't play back in the app.

Is there any way to do this with the accessibility API?

For context - I want to be able to help people record actions in Android and replay them for accessibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, there is no way to do this generally. A touchable overlay will capture all touches, as you're observing. It's not possible to do general-purpose filtering of touch events.

You've probably already thought of this, but if you're playing back pre-recorded gestures, you can remove your overlay before you dispatch them.

The general purpose filtering API doesn't exist because it's very difficult to filter touch events outside the system process without introducing serious jank.

Comment: Hmm, thanks! Can you elaborate on "The general purpose filtering API doesn't exist because it's very difficult to filter touch events outside the system process without introducing serious jank."? Also, I'd be content with just skipping the overlay rather than general filtering of events (so the person recording can see the action when recording it).

Comment: There are many ways to introduce jank when filtering input events. The easiest is to allocate memory, which can lead to garbage collection every once in a while. But I've managed to make the input janky in a variety of ways. Note that skipping the overlay is essentially just another way to build such a filter.

Answer (score 2):

You must use FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE params flag for your view and then dispatch your click.